# How to divide commits into multiple squashes

Tags: git, github, git-commit, git-rebase, git-squash

I need some help with squashing commits in GitHub.

I have about 30 commits and I want to squash the first 10 commits into one single squashed commit and another 10 commits into another squashed commit. I have used `git rebase -i HEAD~10` and squashed the first 10 commits. That works fine. But when I try to squash the next 10 commits, the previously squashed commit also appears in the list. Even though I didn't change the option for squashed commit from "pick" to "squash" that was also included in the resulting squashed commit. As a result I got only one squashed commit.
Can anybody please guide me to get two separate squashed commits as per my requirement.

Thanks in advance

Comment: “I have used git rebase -i HEAD~10 and squashed the first 10 commits.” Show how you configured the pick list when you did that, what the log looked like after, and what you want to do now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `pick` for the first commit in the *new* group; `squash` entries squash onto the *previous* commit.

And for what it's worth, you can do it in a single rebase. If your pick list looks like

```
pick a
squash b
squash c
pick d
squash e
pick f
squash g
squash h
```

You will get one commit with a+b+c squashed, one with d+e, and one with f+g+h.

Comment: Just what I was about to suggest! Nicely put.